# Unable to Install Ubuntu 20.04 on HP Envy 13-ah0001na

Tags: system-installation

When attempting to start the live USB for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS or Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, the system gets stuck waiting for the start jobs ' Userspace Out-of-memory (OOM) Killer', 'Network Name Resolution' and 'Userspace Out-of-memory (OOM) Killer', with a wait time that grows whenever it is met. Ubuntu 21.10 has no issues and boots fine.

Secure Boot is disabled, and nomodeset has been used. Is there any way this issue can be bypassed to install Ubuntu 22?

Update: I was able to have some success by installing Ubuntu 21.10, using apt-mark hold on generic-hwe-20.04 and 5.13.0-19-generic, then replacing all instances of impish in sources.list with jammy. After performing apt update/upgrade I'm left with an install able to access the 22.04.1 package repository, using the 5.13.0-19-generic kernel included in 21.10 which seems to work on my machine.

If anyone has a better solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much RAM is installed?

Comment: 8GB, though not sure how that could affect the live USB

Comment: Ubuntu 22 would mean Ubuntu Core 22 the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number. Can I suggest before trying Ubuntu 22.04 you read over the install steps on this official site. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Hi David, I was abbreviating Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, mentioned earlier in the post, as Ubuntu 22. I have followed those instructions and created a bootable USB which works on other systems, but not this one.